# Library not found for -lRealmReact when building my .xworkspace iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

When I try to build my project.xworkspace

I get an error

```
library not found for -lRealmReact
```

I use cocoapod for my libraries but add `pod Realm` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The CocoaPods version of Realm is the native version of Realm Objective-C for iOS, not React Native. You shouldn't be trying to add that if your project is built on React Native. :)

Please read the [installation instructions](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/) on how to install Realm React Native into an iOS project.